# Django model abstract model with constrains not being inherited: 'constraints' refers to field 'xxx' which is not local to model 'Foo'

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-migrations

I am using Django 3.2

I have come across a strange behaviour which appears to be a bug; Fields used in constraints defined in a ABC are not inherited by child classes.

#### myapp/models.py

```
class BaseFoo(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='%(class)s_content_type')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='%(class)s')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['content_object', 'user'], name="'%(class)s_unique"),
        ]
    
class Foo(BaseFoo):
    class Meta(BaseFoo.Meta):
        abstract = False
```

No problem when I `makemigrations`, but, When I attempt to migrate the schema (`python manage.py migrate), I get the following error:

> myapp.Foo: (models.E016) 'constraints' refers to field 'content_object' which is not local to model 'Foo'.
> HINT: This issue may be caused by multi-table inheritance.

Why is Foo not inheriting the fields clearly defined in the parent ABC? - and how do I fix this (assuming it's not a bug)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** You can't use [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) in `UniqueConstraint`, because a [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) isn’t a normal field object. Instead in `UniqueConstraint` use **`content_type`** and **`object_id`**, this is equivalent to `content_object`:

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=['content_type', 'object_id', 'user'], 
            name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_user_unique"),
    ]
```

See [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey):

> Due to the way [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) is implemented, you cannot use
> such fields directly with filters (**filter()** and **exclude()**, for
> example) via the database API. Because a [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey)
> isn’t a normal field object.
>
> Likewise, [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) does not appear in **ModelForms**.

**2.** According to [**Django Docs**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name) in abstract base classes **`related_name`** must contain '**%(app_label)s**' and '**%(class)s**'. And you should always specify a unique reverse name and query name for the field.

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(
   ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_content_types',
   related_query_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_content_type',
)

user = models.ForeignKey(
    User, blank=False, null=False,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_users',
    related_query_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_user',
)
```

> If you are using **related_name** or **related_query_name** on a
> **ForeignKey** or **ManyToManyField**, you must always specify a unique reverse name and query name for the field. This would normally
> cause a problem in abstract base classes, since the fields on this
> class are included into each of the child classes, with exactly the
> same values for the attributes (including **related_name** and
> **related_query_name**) each time.
>
> To work around this problem, when you are using **related_name** or
> **related_query_name** in an abstract base class (only), part of the value
> should contain '**%(app_label)s**' and '**%(class)s**'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but did you try this yourself? It had no effect on the error. I still have the same errors after I made the suggested changes to my code.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli, just tested. The error is coming from your `UniqueConstraint`. The `content_object` is not a real column. Use instead: `models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['content_type', 'object_id', 'user'], name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_user_unique"),`. I edited my answer.